Viewport shading issue when activating cavity
I have the following issue with viewport shading when activating cavity.
The following is a default startup file:

And here the same, with cavity disabled:

Same thing happens with other models, here with a Suzanne:
cavity disabled:

cavity enabled:

I have played around with some stuff like smooth shading and a view other options, but so far I wasn't able to figure out the reason for this weird shading issue. Anyone know what this could be?

Please check your Clip Start and End settings in the sidepanel's View tab. If the Clip Start is set to a very low value (especially when the End value is very high), then these shading artifacts can appear if Cavity is set to World or Both.

If setting the clipping to a reasonable value alone does not solve the issue, look at the World Space properties in the Cavity settings (the gear icon) and try changing the Distance value to see if it helps (default value is 0.02 m):

Since you said it is in the default startup scene, you probably have messed up the Clip Start setting of the default startup file. So open a completely new scene, change the Clip Start settings to useful values (original defaults are Clip Start: 0.01 m, End: 1000 m), then go to File > Defaults > Save Startup File.

Hmm, you are right on all accounts (I am basically doing the CG Masters "cars:inside and out" course and changed the default file with the settings recommended there..expect for the minimum clip distance. This I had set to a lower value because I simultaneously was working on a project with a very small scale). Setting more reasonable values improves the problem, even if it is not completely gone (especially when zooming out it is still visible). Thank you for the insight!

@RolandDeschain Well, the artifacts usually increase when zooming out, so if it still does that in your scene it means the value is still too low. In general it is not only about if a start value is too low or an end value too high, the range between them is important. It's best to keep the range within a ratio of 10^4 to 10^5 between lowest and highest value. Low start values produce artifacts in perspective view, high end values tend to produce artifacts in orthographic view.
